# Tomcat Doesn't Start

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I have two tomcat7 installed on the same machine (centos 6.4), but in two separate folders.
In the first tomcat I left the default listening ports while in the other one I modified
every port (in the file /conf/server.xml) so that doesn't overlap with the first tomcat.
However, when I start the second tomcat I get this error:

```
`SEVERE: Could not contact localhost:60000. Tomcat may not be running.
Oct 01, 2013 12:29:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Catalina.stop:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:500)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at         sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:458)`
```

I'm sure that no program uses port 60000 because I checked with "netstat -atulpn" before
starting the failing tomcat.

Comment: Are you sure, you are **starting** the server? `Oct 01, 2013 12:29:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Catalina.stop:` means you are trying to **stop** it...

Answer (score 0):

Try these (Hopefully it helps):

- Stop tomcat
- Start tomcat

If issue still exist;

- Issue either: `pkill tomcat` or `killall tomcat`
- Or issue `ps aux | grep tomcat` to list all the PID(s) for tomcat process(es) and issue `kill -9 <pid>` for each found process id.

If issue still exist;

- Issue `vi /etc/hosts` and map your hostname against your host IP address, and then
- Try starting tomcat again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have not opened two IDEs with two Workspaces, one instance of TomCat running will crash the other one. You need to set Java_Home in Catalina.bat file first. Secondly, through command line **cd**  and once your command line shows that you are in that directory type **run startup** . It will start your TomCat Servers, make sure you are not running two tomcat at same time, and they are using different ports. Also, point to **Window --> Preference --> Runtime Environment**. In **Server Runtime Environment**, check that your Tomcat Server is listed. You can solve this issues in multiple ways.